# Save classifier to postrgesql database, in scikit-learn

Tags: postgresql, scikit-learn, persistence

I know that scikit-learn models can be persisted in files, by using joblib (as described here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).
However, since i have machine learning procedure inside postgresql plpythonu function, I would rather persist the model inside the Postgresql database.

What is recommended, the most convinient way to store scikit-learn model inside a Postgresql database?

Comment: Some kind of [blob-storage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB) and joblib's [supported](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/pull/351) dump to some in-memory buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code in Python for sending the trained model to a Postgres table. Note that you first need to create a table that has a column with the "bytea" type to store the pickled sklearn model in binary format.

```py
from sklearn import svm
    
import psycopg2
import pickle
    
#### # Connect to Postgres
    
connection = psycopg2.connect(user, password, host, port, database)
cur = connection.cursor()
model = svm.OneClassSVM()
model.fit(features)   # features are some training data
data = pickle.dumps(model)    # first we should pickle the model
    
#### # Assuming you have a Postgres table with columns epoch and file

sql = "INSERT INTO sampletable (epoch, file) VALUES(%s)"
cur.execute(sql, (epoch, psycopg2.Binary(data)))
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Django you can binarize a sci-kit learn model

using pickle and then save it to
a table that has a BinaryField member.

**A simple example:**

*views.py (saving)*

```
from sklearn import svm
import pickle
from ml.models import MlModels
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def save(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    X = [[0.12, 22, 33, 100], [0.19, 19, 99, 33], [0.5, 50, 150, 0]]
    y = [1, 0, 1]
    model = svm()
    model.fit(X=X, y=y)
    data = pickle.dumps(model)
    MlModels.objects.create(model=data)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

class MlModels(models.Model):
    model       =   models.BinaryField()
```

*views.py (using)*

```
import pickle
from ml.models import MlModels
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def predict(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        X = [[0.12, 22, 33, 100]]
        raw_model = MlModel.objects.all()[0]
        model = pickle.loads(raw_model.model)
        print(model.predict(X))
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```